# Generating a URL with server name

Tags: php, routes, yii2

I'm reading [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names) Yii2 part of the documentation that describes how to map server names to actions.

I have this rule: `'http://<slug:\w+>.example.com/edit-info/' =>  'ctrl/edit-info',` which works fine, but I'm not sure how to generate a link that would match that rule.

Things like:

```
Url::to(["foo-bar.example.com", "ctrl/edit-info"]);
```

won't work.

Is there any way to generate such a link or should I just do it on my own, concatenating each part (scheme, slug, domain, etc etc etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Url::to(["ctrl/edit-info", "slug" => "foo-bar"]);
```

Comment: You're right. That worked. I wasn't expecting it to work, but it did.